# Adding an auto-incrementing number to a file name string

Tags: powershell

I would like my PowerShell script to modify the name of the file by increment number every time.

This is my file name: `abc-0.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip`.
I want to write a syntax that will increment it every time like mentioned below:

```
abc-0.2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.3-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.5-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.6-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.7-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.8-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.9-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.10-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
abc-0.2.0.11-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
```

and so on …

Comment: `if ("abc-0.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip" -match "(abc-(\d+.){3})(\d+)(-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip)") { "$($Matches[1])$([Int]::Parse($Matches[3])+1)$($Matches[4])"}`

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression replacement with a callback function:

```
$name = 'abc-0.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip'

[regex]$re = '(.*?\.)(\d+)(-SNAPSHOT-.*\.zip)'
$cb = {
    $a, $b, $c = $args[0].Groups[1..3].Value
    '{0}{1}{2}' -f $a, ([int]$b+1), $c
}

$re.Replace($name, $cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the highest number you need to first get them to an equal length, otherwise with alpha sorting 10 is less than 9.

---

I was still struggling with the RegEx but Ansgar was faster, so I'll combine these two parts

```
$Last = Get-ChildItem abc-*-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip | 
  Sort-Object {[Regex]::Replace($($_.Basename),'\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(10, '0')})}|
    Select -Last 1

[regex]$re = '(.*?\.)(\d+)(-SNAPSHOT-.*\.zip)'
$cb = {
      $a, $b, $c = $args[0].Groups[1..3].Value
      '{0}{1}{2}' -f $a, ([int]$b+1), $c
}
$re.Replace($Last.Name, $cb)
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\08\18\SO_45748408.ps1
abc-0.2.0.12-SNAPSHOT-barista.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the 0.2.0.x bit to a variable

```
$version = 3
```

Then everytime you perform an action increase that variable by one
ie.

```
*perform action*
$version++
```